# How can I set a timestamp flag to true without using a date in Laravel and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a few flag columns in my model, such as `disabled_at`, `published_at`, etc. These are all timestamp flags, so they either store a NULL value (i.e. not disabled, not published) or a timestamp of when they were disabled or published. I'm dealing with some legacy data migration right now and I don't have the timestamps for the disabling and publishing of certain rows, so what value would be best to store in these columns?

Laravel's soft-delete feature documentation says any non-null value is considered as a set flag, which seems fine, but if I just go ahead and put `1` in the columns I mentioned, it will be a problem when casting the columns as Carbon objects.

If I add a custom attribute, for eg. `$model->disabled`, I could make the first one check for a non-null value in `$model->disabledAt` and return the appropriate boolean value, but the casting problem persists.

Keeping both `disabled` as well as `disabledAt` is obviously not something I'm looking to do.

I'm using Laravel and MySQL, but this is something that should apply to any system in theory.

Comment: you could pass sample timestamp value

Comment: Is there some way you can use mutators/accessors to solve this? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators That is do set the DB value to 1. But then when accessing it turn all 1's into null

Comment: disabled_at should be easy enough, if the legacy row is disabled, you can put any date in there or leave it NULL and it will work.  With regards to published at, are you saying you have some legacy rows that are published, ie not disabled, but have no published date?